# PowerShell script to set black and white/grayscale on Xerox Phaser printers

Tags: powershell, network-printers

We manage a large number of Xerox Phaser 6600 printers, is there a script to set the printers to black and white printing?

The only alternative way is to manually going to the devices and printers > printing preferences > image options > tick the box "Xerox Black and White conversion"

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can't you simply do this setting on the printer server and have users reconnect the printer?

Comment: If you've got a large number of those printers you've likely got a support contract too, contact support and ask them for advice. I can guarantee you won't be the first person to ask this as it's a common request for a print server setup.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for all your replies. We do not use a printer server to manage the printers. All of our printers are networked, so they have an IP address assigned.

Comment: I tried entering this PowerShell script

set-printConfiguration -computername xxxxx -printername xxxxxx -color $false, but get an error message the term 'set-printconfiguration' is not recognised as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file or operable program.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to set the default on the printer, you can make a powershell+curl script to do this.  When I worked at Xerox I did this type of stuff for a few models and it's pretty easy.  You just need to pass in the basic authentication token, the page url for the setting page you're doing this on, and the field values for the form.

There may be an SNMP setting for this as well.  I don't have the Xerox mibs in front of me, but that would be the easiest way to do it if you can find them.

If you're trying to do this on the PCs you can usually set some registry or file settings with the driver.  I would expect sales support to help with that.